# how to get number portion from a string in java?

Tags: java

I have a string like

```
String video_link="http://vimeo.com/81988791"
```

Now I want the last   portion of this string `81988791`?

Thanks.

Comment: "How?" - By writing a code that instructs the computer to do so.

Comment: is it always the last 8 letters? Or at the end of hte string? Or after the last /?

Comment: We can guide you and point you in the right direction, but don't expect anyone here to give you the complete solution without first seeing some work from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
String video_link="http://vimeo.com/81988791"
int number = Integer.parseInt(video_link.substring("http://vimeo.com/".length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

use a regex. java has good regex support: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("http://vimeo.com/(d+)").matcher(input)
System.out.println(m.group(1))
```

Comment: While this is a correct answer, I don't think we should provide a solution for questions like this one.

Comment: A clueless programmer will one day google this question, and perhaps make use of this simple answer. I dont think you (or anyone) should judge whether a question deserves answering or not.

Comment: @Chii: I am on android application developing. Not works.. get Error
like: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Pattern to Matcher

Comment: @Chii I'm telling my opinion. You are welcome to accept it or not. However, *anyone* includes SO, but the **do judge** what questions should be answered, FYI.